# How to change out ammo?

Tags: world-of-tanks

In World of Tanks on an Xbox 360, how does one change out ammo while in battle?  Or how do you change it period?

Answer (score 1):

It depends on your controller buttons settings. On the default set, you can change ammo in battle pressing A button.

[image]

Note that not every tank has ammo to switch by default.